# flash has mxml microsoft has xaml What has java?

Tags: java, xaml, mxml, markup

Flash has MXML and Microsoft has XAML.

What markup languages does Java have?

Comment: markup languages for designing applications; better with developer tools

Comment: @Blender: Note that your question can be somewhat ambiguous (the JSML answer is a valid answer, considering the question). I guess you wanted markup languages for UI (user interfaces), and thus, you should have given that information in your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAML and MXML are UI markups for WPF and Flex.  The equivalent Java tool is JavaFX.  With that Sun took a different approach and choose to implement a declarative scripting language - [JavaFX Script](http://www.sun.com/software/javafx/script/) - rather than use an extension to XML.

Comment: Note that XAML (or any XML format, anyway) is not an extension to XML. It **is** XML. Any XML parser can read/write/interpret XAML (or X-HTML, or XUL, etc.) as XML. BTW, your link is dead. Perhaps this one has the same content: http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/javafx/overview/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Any markup language can be interpreted by any language or platform capable or parsing text. This depends on the application, and this in fact the benefit of the markup language in the first place - neutrality of the implementor. I think your question is not entirely correct. There are trillions of projects and products using markup in java.